# SITECORE: Invalid Scope Offline(Facebook)

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-mvc, sitecore-social-connected

I get the following error when I login via facebook using social connector in sitecore 8.[image]

I think the issue is related to the update facebook made last april. How to solve this issue?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I just need to disable offline access in Sitecore.Social.Facebook.config.

```
 <setting name="Social.Facebook.IsOfflineAccess" value="false" />
```